# How to force page break beetwen records in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to force page break after each record from datasource. I tried `<break type="Page">`, but doesn't work. How to do that ?

Comment: It works fine. I've put `<break type="Page">` to the **Detail** band and it works. Can you post the jrxml file snippet? I'm using JR 4.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it using `<group>`:

```
<group name="record" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

Comment: Thanks, also for those not very sure on where to place the <group>, there are a few examples at http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/misc/tools/jasper/groups.html

Comment: @mariooch Thank you for this. I used it to limit the number of rows displayed in a table using $V{REPORT_COUNT}/10 so I have 10 rows in each page