# How do I set the number of rows to be displayed per page in a report

Tags: jasper-reports

How do I set the number of rows to be displayed per page in a report using JasperReports. I am using java beans as data source.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JasperReport set number of records per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045491/jasperreport-set-number-of-records-per-page). You can also see the answer on [How to force page break beetwen records in Jasper Reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698857/how-to-force-page-break-beetwen-records-in-jasper-reports) question

Comment: Another similar post: [How do I limit the number of rows on each page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617082/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-on-each-page)

Comment: Welcome on SO! You can always use Search engine on SO before posting the new question

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific option to set the number of rows per page. However, you could set a condition that a new page is generated when

$V{REPORT_COUNT} == $P{SOME_NUMBER}

where SOME_NUMBER is a parameter set by you and REPORT_COUNT is a built-in variable holding the numbers of records currently processed. This can be set as a printWhenExpression property on the main detail band of the page.

Comment: About what condition (`However, you could set a condition that a new page is generated when`) are you talking?

Comment: @Alex K I have amended my answer.